# Summing numbers and letters in Excel

Tags: excel

Is there a way to sum the following cells in B, C and D columns, so that they display the values below?

[image]

The numbers can go up to two digits, while the letters are always one letter.

What is this about? It is a sort (simplified on the screenshot above, of course) of gantt chart, with the description of activities in the leftmost column, and with the dates on top. A, B and C are codes for various types of workers, and I need a way to assign various numbers of workers to a specific activity on a specific date. In the end, I need a way to tell how much workers will be on the site on any given day (therefore, the need to sum the values above into the A, B and C categories below).

Edit: *I'm currently googling the functions mentioned in the comments, but cannot figure out a way to sum them up using those functions.*

Comment: LEFT, LEN and RIGHT functions...?

Comment: And then SUMIF.

Comment: You specify "two cells".  Do you mean that `20A, 3B, 3C` is all in a single cell and `2A, 3B, 3C` is also all in a single cell?

Comment: @SJR - Could you provide a working example? Taking into account that there are commas and spaces in between.

Comment: @tigeravatar - Yeah, sorry about that. Yes, A, B and C is in the left column, while the sum of letters is in the right column. Yes, "20A, 3B, 3C" is in one cell.

Comment: So text to columns first?

Comment: @SJR - Sorry, not sure what you mean by "So text to columns first?".

Comment: Data -> Data Tools -> Text to Columns

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - Yeah, ok, but that's gonna split it into different cells. I need a way to sum them up without modifying the structure of the worksheet. To put it (maybe incorrectly terms wise) I need a way to parse it, and then sum it (the values).

Comment: I think it's going to be quite a faff without VBA, if it's possible at all. And a screenshot would help as precise set up not entirely clear.

Comment: @SJR - Quite right. Added a screenshot, so hoping it will clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 2):

For the sample shown, and whether or not single or double digits, in respectively B7, B8 and B9 and copied across:

```
=IF(FIND("A",B3)=2,LEFT(B3),LEFT(B3,2))+IF(FIND("A",B4)=2,LEFT(B4),LEFT(B4,2))+IF(FIND("A",B5)=2,LEFT(B5),LEFT(B5,2))  

=MID(B3,FIND("B",B3)-2,2)+MID(B4,FIND("B",B4)-2,2)+MID(B5,FIND("B",B5)-2,2)  

=MID(B3,FIND("C",B3)-2,2)+MID(B4,FIND("C",B4)-2,2)+MID(B5,FIND("C",B5)-2,2)
```

should give the numeric results shown as required for the given sample.

Comment: No, activities are just descriptions. I really did not notice that I named them "Activity A", B and C up until now, but I had to name them somehow. If this was confusing, it could have been asked in the comments, but since nobody did ask, obviously nobody put those two in the same categogy. Neither did I.

Comment: Data sample as image? At first, it was explained through text, then somebody asked for a screenshot, deeming it easier that way. I also think it is more clear this way.

Comment: The number of activities range in the hundreds.

Comment: "layout for the data source that is unlikely to be chosen by (almost) anyone else". What do you mean? This is actually a standard layout while doing this sort of things. I also did not understand what you meant under "poor choice of tool (though, as for layout, that might be unavoidable) - i.e. no regex".

Comment: Really, as much as I agree with you on the point of clarity, and that it is better to be explicit than ambiguous, I find that a lot of comments in the first paragraph is just nitpicking. And don't really have to do with the problem at hand. For example, I don't see the relevance of how the format of the date influences anything in this mattter.

Comment: Off to try the examples, and to try to understand them. I've never used any of the mentioned functions, so will probably comment further tomorrow, upon reading a bit on each and every one of them.